# Fluid pressure at a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics, density

If there be $n$ fluids arranged in strata of equal thickness and the density of the uppermost be $\rho$, of the next $2\rho$, and so on, that of the last being $n\rho$: find the pressure at the lowest point of the $n$th stratum.
This question appeared in our exams, and I remember doing it using the formula $F=wsz$ and the formula for sum of an Arithmetic progression. Now, I'm checking out how much am I scoring by finding out the correct answer.
I seriously don't remember the concept since it has been a long time and I can't access my books since I returned them to the library.

Comment: What is w, s, z in your formula

Answer (score 1):

$$P = \rho g h$$

for strata of equal thickness and the given densities, the pressure at the bottom would be

$$P_{bottom} = (1+2+3+ \ldots +n) \rho g h $$

Use the formula for the sum of arithmetic progression for the sum in brackets and you'll get the answer.